# Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition while executing in Powershell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I'm new to powershell. When I'm trying to execute the below code I'm getting the error:

> "Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition."

Below is the code and I'm not sure where I'm missing.

```
$path = "C:\Users\Dr.Salya\Downloads"
$filename = "rateonlyl-455.zip"

$url = "https://vertexinc.custhelp.com/app/utils/login_form"
$url2 = "https://download-ie.flexnetoperations.com/512175/1386/77/17129077/rateonlyl-455.zip?ftpRequestID=2321180473&server=download-ie.flexnetoperations.com&dtm=DTM20200820125043ODA0MDU5NDEz&authparam=1597953043_bf5ca04b9a74eeb53a272c20ea148517&ext=.zip/"

$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application

$ie.visible = $true
$ie.silent = $false

$ie.navigate("$url")

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4){start-sleep -m 100}
if ($ie.document.url -Match "invalidcert"){
$sslbypass=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where-object {$_.id -eq "overridelink"}
    $sslbypass.click()
    start-sleep -s 5
    }
 

$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("username").click()
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("username").value ='********'
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("password").click()
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("password").value ='1234'
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("").click()

start-sleep 5

$ie.navigate($url2)

start-sleep 10

$ie.Document.body.outerHTML | Out-File -FilePath $path/$filename
```

Error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Dr.Salya\Downloads\Vertex1.ps1:22 char:1
+ $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("username").click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\Dr.Salya\Downloads\Vertex1.ps1:23 char:1
+ $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("username").value ='nnaisv ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Dr.Salya\Downloads\Vertex1.ps1:24 char:1
+ $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("password").click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\Dr.Salya\Downloads\Vertex1.ps1:25 char:1
+ $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("password").value ='Vertex ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Dr.Salya\Downloads\Vertex1.ps1:26 char:1
+ $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("").click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: I couldn't login, because of incorrect credentials. Is there a chance that you provide a read-only temporary access.

Comment: Were you able to go till giving in login credentials? I cant really give any kind of access due to some security issues.... I'm getting an error while executing the if body. Is there anything else i need to change?

Comment: Your original error is solved? You have a new error?  Your new error is `$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("username").click()` and most likely `$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("username")` is returning `$null`

Comment: No my original error is not solved. When the program is not executing i used F8 to execute each statement separately. That's when i encountered the first error The other which i posted after running the entire program...

Comment: You have to solve the null valued error before we can help with your syntax problem.  Use the appropriate tools to debug your code and use breakpoints (I.e PowerShell ISE)

Comment: “If the click call did not throw a NullReferenceException, then you found the element.“

Comment: As for this... [I'm new to powershell]... that is all well a good (as we all started like that), but did you spend any cycles getting ramped up on it first. Like reading 'PowerShell in a month of lunches', or visiting Youtube and review the 'Begining PowerShell' and 'PowerShell and web scraping' and 'PowerShell browser automation'. Studying these lead to limiting and eliminating frustration, confusion, misconceptions, bad code, bad habits, etc. Well, for the most part they do. Yet, we are all human and well, you know... ;-}

Comment: Sure postanote. I started looking at them...Thanks for your Positive Vibes about this course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to scrape the page to make sure you are getting the right object/element and do that one use case at a time. As well as if the object/element has the properties, methods you need to resolve your use case.

For example, just getting the login stuff working.

```
# $path     = "C:\Users\Dr.Salya\Downloads"
# $filename = "rateonlyl-455.zip"

$url  = "https://vertexinc.custhelp.com/app/utils/login_form"
# $url2 = "https://download-ie.flexnetoperations.com/512175/1386/77/17129077/rateonlyl-455.zip?ftpRequestID=2321180473&server=download-ie.flexnetoperations.com&dtm=DTM20200820125043ODA0MDU5NDEz&authparam=1597953043_bf5ca04b9a74eeb53a272c20ea148517&ext=.zip/"

$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application

$ie.visible = $true
$ie.silent = $false
$ie.navigate($url)
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4){start-sleep -m 100}

if ($ie.document.url -Match "invalidcert")
{
    $sslbypass = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('a') | 
                 where-object {$_.id -eq "overridelink"}
    $sslbypass.click()
    start-sleep -s 5
}
 
$ie.Document.forms | 
Select-Object className, id, tagName, innerText, outerText 
# Results
<#
className : rn_OpenLoginForm rn_OAuthForm
id        : rn_OpenLogin_6_Info
tagName   : FORM
innerText :  
            
            What will happen:
            When you click on this button you will be taken to Yahoo. 
            Once you log in, Yahoo will verify you and send you back here where 
            you'll be logged in! 
outerText :  
            
            What will happen:
            When you click on this button you will be taken to Yahoo. 
            Once you log in, Yahoo will verify you and send you back here where 
            you'll be logged in! 

className : 
id        : rn_LoginForm_7_Form
tagName   : FORM
innerText : Username (Your email address)
            
            Password
            
             
outerText : Username (Your email address)
            
            Password
#>

$ie.Document.forms.item('rn_LoginForm_7_Form') | 
Select-Object -Property className, Name, id, Type, Value, ie9_tagName | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
className name             id                      type     value  ie9_tagName
--------- ----             --                      ----     -----  -----------
          Contact.Login    rn_LoginForm_7_Username text            INPUT      
          Contact.Password rn_LoginForm_7_Password password        INPUT      
                           rn_LoginForm_7_Submit   submit   Log In INPUT 
#>


$ie.Document.getElementById('rn_LoginForm_7_Username').Value = 'SomeUserName'
$ie.Document.getElementById('rn_LoginForm_7_Password').Value = 'Password'
$ie.Document.getElementById('rn_LoginForm_7_Submit').Click()
```

... then go to the next page, if any, as this site does. Yet, since I don't have an account to use on this site, I cannot execute and further actions. Yet, just pulling a list of links, even from the login page, would be the same for any subsequent page.

```
$ie.Document.links | 
ForEach-Object {
[PSCustomObject]@{
    className   = $PSItem.className
    tagName     = $PSItem.tagName
    innerText   = $PSitem.innerText
    outerText   = $PSitem.outerText
    href        = $PSItem.href 
    ClickMethod = $PSItem.Click
}}

# Results
<#

className   : 
tagName     : A
innerText   :  | myVertex
outerText   :  | myVertex
href        : javascript:void
ClickMethod : void click ()

className   : rn_LoginProvider rn_Yahoo
tagName     : A
innerText   : Yahoo
outerText   : Yahoo
href        : javascript:void(0)
ClickMethod : void click ()

className   : 
tagName     : A
innerText   : Forgot your password?
outerText   : Forgot your password?
href        : https://vertexinc.custhelp.com/app/utils/account_assistance/session/L3RpbWUvMTU5ODA0OTI1Ni9nZW4vMTU5ODA0OTI1Ni9zaWQvZlU4S0VoTlNVd2lJVjh1bmZDcTVVUHFvWWRF
              TFZOVDVPU3JNYXJWeWV3SXdsYSU3RUclN0VjQ3VOc1BTaWtxbGFmMkFKclY0bGZYcTZaa1B4T1g1cF9ISVhRbVpwaXF5c3ZQbUVIYVNjckhLR3ByazNYRDNfaDBQQVZXQSUyMSUyMQ%3D%3D
ClickMethod : void click ()

className   : 
tagName     : A
innerText   : Sign Up
outerText   : Sign Up
href        : https://vertexinc.custhelp.com/app/utils/create_account/redirect/utils%252Faccount_confirmation/session/L3RpbWUvMTU5ODA0OTI1Ni9nZW4vMTU5ODA0OTI1Ni9zaWQv
              ZlU4S0VoTlNVd2lJVjh1bmZDcTVVUHFvWWRFTFZOVDVPU3JNYXJWeWV3SXdsYSU3RUclN0VjQ3VOc1BTaWtxbGFmMkFKclY0bGZYcTZaa1B4T1g1cF9ISVhRbVpwaXF5c3ZQbUVIYVNjckhLR3ByazNY
              RDNfaDBQQVZXQSUyMSUyMQ%3D%3D
ClickMethod : void click ()

className   : 
tagName     : A
innerText   :  
outerText   :  
href        : https://vertexinc.custhelp.com/app/home/session/L3RpbWUvMTU5ODA0OTI1Ni9nZW4vMTU5ODA0OTI1Ni9zaWQvZlU4S0VoTlNVd2lJVjh1bmZDcTVVUHFvWWRFTFZOVDVPU3JNYXJWeWV3
              SXdsYSU3RUclN0VjQ3VOc1BTaWtxbGFmMkFKclY0bGZYcTZaa1B4T1g1cF9ISVhRbVpwaXF5c3ZQbUVIYVNjckhLR3ByazNYRDNfaDBQQVZXQSUyMSUyMQ%3D%3D
ClickMethod : void click ()

className   : 
tagName     : A
innerText   : Privacy Policy
outerText   : Privacy Policy
href        : javascript:showPrivacyPolicy();
ClickMethod : void click ()

className   : 
tagName     : A
innerText   : Terms of Use
outerText   : Terms of Use
href        : javascript:showTerms();
ClickMethod : void click ()

className   : 
tagName     : A
innerText   :   Contact: 1-800-281-1900
outerText   :   Contact: 1-800-281-1900
href        : tel:1-800-281-1900
ClickMethod : void click ()

className   : 
tagName     : A
innerText   : 
outerText   : 
href        : https://www.facebook.com/vertexinc1/
ClickMethod : void click ()

className   : 
tagName     : A
innerText   : 
outerText   : 
href        : https://twitter.com/vertexinc
ClickMethod : void click ()

className   : 
tagName     : A
innerText   : 
outerText   : 
href        : https://www.linkedin.com/company/vertex-inc.
ClickMethod : void click ()

className   : 
tagName     : A
innerText   : 
outerText   : 
href        : https://www.youtube.com/user/vertexinc
ClickMethod : void click ()         
#>

$ie.Document.links | 
Select-Object -Property outerText, href
# Results
<#
outerText             href                                                                                           
---------             ----                                                                                           
 | myVertex           javascript:void                                                                                
Yahoo                 javascript:void(0)                                                                             
Forgot your password? https://vertexinc.custhelp.com/app/utils/account_assistance                                    
Sign Up               https://vertexinc.custhelp.com/app/utils/create_account/redirect/utils%252Faccount_confirmation
                      https://vertexinc.custhelp.com/app/home/                                                       
Privacy Policy        javascript:showPrivacyPolicy();                                                                
Terms of Use          javascript:showTerms();                                                                        
  Contact: 1-800-2... tel:1-800-281-1900                                                                             
                      https://www.facebook.com/vertexinc1/                                                           
                      https://twitter.com/vertexinc                                                                  
                      https://www.linkedin.com/company/vertex-inc.                                                   
                      https://www.youtube.com/user/vertexinc 
#>


$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A')[4] | 
ForEach-Object {
[PSCustomObject]@{
    className   = $PSItem.className
    id          = $PSItem.id
    tagName     = $PSItem.tagName
    innerText   = $PSitem.innerText
    outerText   = $PSitem.outerText
    href        = $PSItem.href 
    ClickMethod = $PSItem.Click
}}
# Results
<#
className   : 
id          : 
tagName     : A
innerText   : Sign Up
outerText   : Sign Up
href        : https://vertexinc.custhelp.com/app/utils/create_account/redirect/utils%252Faccount_confirmation
ClickMethod : void click ()
#>


($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | 
Where outerText -eq 'Forgot your password?').Click()
    
($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | 
Where outerText -eq 'Sign Up').Click()
```

The final thing, you can automate sites that allow it. Some site(s) allow no automation of their properties (or parts of it), they actively code them to prevent it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @postanote for a wonderful walk through... I'm able to analyse it easily now..

Comment: After successfully login i was trying to click another link in the page. I got all the Tagname and outer text details. I have included them in the below command but it's throwing "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." error.

I was  trying to access the Nissan North America Inc. - 2554002 link but it's throwing error. ($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where outerText -eq 'Nissan North America Inc. - 2554002').Click()

Comment: No worries, yet, remember, I cannot get to that page, thus no way of analyzing what it is really doing. Every site developer, may or may not design pages the same way. Burying stuff in Div, frames, et al, require a different approach. When you are scraping the page and use the 'dot' and IntelliSense does not show the method, in your case, click then what you called is not valid and you have to keep digging until you find the one that does have that method or property you need to work with. null-valued means it's empty of course.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue @Postanote. Thanks Again. In one of the pages i was trying to download the zip file and i was able to download it but in IE it was promting to open or save which i was unsure how to handle that piece in code. Is there anyother way that we can automate that?

Comment: Glad to hear you were successful on that other page. If the page provides the link to the file, then just use one of these options in your code to get the file. ['PowerShell download file from the web'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell+download+file+from+the+web%27&t=h_&ia=web)